# need to pass parameter to Unix script at run time

Tags: python, unix

I have shell code which need to be initialised with python variable

Note : the var is a python variable which holds value `/d/demo/f.txt`

Need to pass the python variable `var` to my below shell script

```
var='/d/demo/f.txt'

script="""

( 
echo "From : xyz"
echo "To : xyz"
cat var
) |sendmail -t 

"""
os.system("bash -c '%s' % script ")
```

The var value assigned is not passed to `cat var`
Any solution is appreciated

Comment: Why are you using `os.system()` to send mail? Python has libraries for this.

Comment: @Barmar : Because i don't library installed and it's restricted from installing

Comment: Huh? `email` and `smtplib` are installed along with Python itself.

Comment: Unless the file starts with an empty line, your script is broken. The spaces before the colons are also quite irregular, though I guess they won't block delivery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an f-string to substitute the variable into the script. Use `shlex.quote()` to escape it in case it has special characters.

```
import shlex

var='/d/demo/f.txt'
from='xyz'
to='xyz'

script=rf"""

( 
printf 'From: %s\nTo: %s\n' {shlex.quote(from)} {shlex.quote(to)}
cat {shlex.quote(var)}
) |sendmail -t 

"""
os.system(script)
```

Comment: I added that to the answer. There's no need for `bash -c`.

Comment: @Barmar : if i want to take variable to From and To email id's same shlex quote will work

Comment: Yes, why would it be any different?

Comment: @Barmar : The answer seems to be interesting , will test with my environment is it possible to create python function and pass parameter at run time to the embed Unix script. As far i know most of the time i tried creating bas script with .sh and called in python with `os.system(sh script.sh)`

Comment: @codeholic24 : Can you check and share the script with me it will be helpful for me